# how can i access control in user control from master page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a label in user control and i want to access this control from master page.

I do not use `<%@ Register TagPrefix="..." TagName="..." Src=".." %>` for user control in head of master page.

How can i access this control?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

I am trying to create a shopping website. In my site, I have a small shopping bag on the left side of the header. There are a few items in my shopping bag and Users will be able to delete this items. My shopping bag is located inside master page. On the other hand, I have a user control(for example: ShoppingBagCtrl.ascx) in user account page (for example: MainUserPage.aspx) that shows the number of items in shopping bag and extras. When user Login in site, he was redirected to this page. Inside this page, i use ShoppingBagCtrl.ascx.

My question is:

How can i access to for example a label in user control(ShoppingBagCtrl.ascx) from master page. My user control inside MainUserPage.aspx page and MainUserPage.aspx inside master page. In other words, When user removes items in shopping bag that is located inside master page, label inside user control that is located in MainUserPage.aspx also changed.

Note:

1- Label show number of items in shopping bag.

2- Remove fire by button inside shopping bag.

3- Shopping bag inside master page.

4- Label inside user control.

5- User control inside MainUserPage and MainUserPage inside master page.

I hope I have explained clearly. Thanks a lot.

Master Page :

```
    <div class="HeaderDiv">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="buy-bag">
       <div class="left bag-inner">
        <ul class="right sky-mega-menu sky-mega-menu-anim-scale">
          <li class="dropdown right" aria-haspopup="true">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>your shopping bag : </span>
            <asp:Label ID="ItemLBL" runat="server" CssClass="orange"></asp:Label>
            <span> - </span><asp:Label ID="PriceLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <b class="caret"></b>
           </a>
           <div class="grid-container6">
             <div class="dropdown-inner form">
               //my shopping bag
               <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveBTN" runat="server" text="Remove" OnClick="RemoveBTN_Click">
               </asp:LinkButton>
             </div>
           </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="CenterDiv">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </div>
```

MainUserPage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserCtrl" TagName="ShopingBagCtrl" Src="UserControls/ShopingBagCtrl.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <div class="main container">
        <div class="col-right">
            <UserCtrl:ShopingBagCtrl runat="server" id="UcShopingBagCtrl"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

User Control:

```
<div class="block block-account">
  <div class="block-content">
    <div class="summary" dir="rtl">
      <asp:Label ID="ItemLBL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Master Page cs:

```
protected void RemoveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //I want when click on RemoveBTN on Master Page, I have access to ItemLBL on User Control.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following -

```
UserControl uch = Page.Master.FindControl("userControlId") as UserControl;
Label lbl1= uch.FindControl("labelid") as Label;
```

EDIT -

Below code works for me.

```
protected void RemoveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ContentPlaceHolder cp = this.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
        if (cp != null)
        {
            var userCtrl = (UserControl)cp.FindControl("UcShopingBagCtrl");
            if (userCtrl != null)
            {
                var lbl = userCtrl.FindControl("ItemLBL") as Label;
                if (lbl != null)
                {
                    string txt = lbl.Text;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean of "userControlId"? user control has no ID? Please Help me.

Comment: Can you share code of how you have placed usercontrol?

Comment: OK. But can you show your declaration code in master page. This will help to show you code sample.

Comment: Mark it as answer if answer satisfies what you required.